# Updating Composer- Error: There are no commands defined in the C namespace

Tags: composer-php, invalidargumentexception

I was trying to update my composer through terminal after receiving notification that it's too old using this code `C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\composer.phar self-update`
and i get this error

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   There are no commands defined in the "C" namespace

What is wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you simply run `composer self-update`?